# How to prevent Tkinter labelframe size changes when an empty label is inserted

Tags: python, widget, tkinter, size

I create a LabelFrame widget. It has a nice size in the beginning:

```
import Tkinter
form = Tkinter.Tk()

errorArea = Tkinter.LabelFrame(form, text=" Errors ", width=250, height=80)
errorArea.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="E", \
             padx=5, pady=0, ipadx=0, ipady=0)
```

[image]

But when I insert an empty string in it, the `errorArea` widget's size adjusts according to the inserted string:

```
errorMessage = Tkinter.Label(errorArea, text="")
errorMessage.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=2, sticky='W')
```

[image]

How do I give the `errorArea` widget a fixed size, so that its size won't change according to Lable inserted in it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That problem always was interesting to me.  One way I found to fix it is by using the `place` method instead of `grid`:

```
import Tkinter

form = Tkinter.Tk()

errorArea = Tkinter.LabelFrame(form, text=" Errors ", width=250, height=80)
errorArea.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="E", \
             padx=5, pady=0, ipadx=0, ipady=0)

errorMessage = Tkinter.Label(errorArea, text="")

# 1) 'x' and 'y' are the x and y coordinates inside 'errorArea'
# 2) 'place' uses 'anchor' instead of 'sticky'
# 3) There is no need for 'padx' and 'pady' with 'place'
# since you can specify the exact coordinates
errorMessage.place(x=10, y=10, anchor="w")

form.mainloop()
```

With this, the label is placed in the window without shrinking the labelframe.

Comment: @Downvoter: Could you please give a reason you downvoted?  I care a lot about the quality of my work.  Hence, if you found a problem with my code, please let me know what it is so that I can either fix my post or explain better what I did.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a sticky value that sticks the widget to all four sides of its cell rather than just one side, it won't shrink when you put a small label widget in it.

Another option is to call `errorArea.grid_propagate(False)`, which tells the grid area not to shrink or expand to fit its contents. This will often result in undesirable resize behavior, or at least require you to do a little extra work to get the right resize behavior.

Comment: it didn't work, when I use "WENS" in errorArea, it messes the structure of form.

Comment: If you could show us more of your code we could probably fix the layout issue.

Answer (score -1):

Use the grid function immediately after declaring the Labelframe.

EX :

```
String_l = ttk.Labelframe(pw, text='String',width=100, height=408).grid(column=1, row=0, padx=4, pady=4,rowspan=2)
```